# Props is still empty after mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working in a mern stack app and when I try to pass the state to specific component's props I get errors.

I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

D:/Mohammed/project/mern-app/client/src/components/ShoppingList.js:19
  16 |        this.props.deleteItem(id);
  17 |    }
  18 | 
> 19 |    render() {
     | ^  20 |        const { items } = this.props.item;
  21 |    return (
  22 |      <div>
```

here's the repo for my code:
https://github.com/mohamedsaad4/mern-app

Here's mern-app/client/src/App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Navbars } from './components/Navbar';
import { ShoppingList } from './components/ShoppingList';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbars />
          <ShoppingList />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and here's mern-app/client/src/components/ShoppingList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import {  CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getItems, deleteItem } from '../actions/itemActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


export class ShoppingList extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getItems();
    }

    deleteClick = (id) => {
        this.props.deleteItem(id);
    }

    render() {
        const { items } = this.props.item;
    return (
      <div>
          <Container>
              <ListGroup>
                  <TransitionGroup className="shopping-list">
                    {
                        items.map(({id, name}) => (
                            <CSSTransition key={id} timeout={500} classNames='fade'>
                                <ListGroupItem>
                                    <Button
                                        className='remove-btn'
                                        color='danger'
                                        size='sm'
                                        onClick={this.deleteClick.bind(this, id)}
                                    >&times;</Button>
                                     {name}
                                </ListGroupItem>
                            </CSSTransition>
                        ))
                    }
                  </TransitionGroup>
              </ListGroup>
          </Container>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ShoppingList.propTypes = {
    getItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    item: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        item: state.item
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getItems, deleteItem })(ShoppingList);
```

and here's mern-app/client/src/store.js

```
import { compose, applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
   applyMiddleware(...middleware)
));

export default store;
```

and here's mern-app/client/src/actions/itemActions.js

```
import { GET_ITEMS, ADD_ITEM, DELETE_ITEM } from './types';

export const getItems =  () => {
    return {
        type: GET_ITEMS
    };
};

export const deleteItem =  (id) => {
    return {
        type: DELETE_ITEM,
        payload: id
    };
};
```

and here's mern-app/client/src/actions/types.js

```
export const GET_ITEMS = 'GET_ITEMS';
export const ADD_ITEM = 'ADD_ITEM';
export const DELETE_ITEM = 'DELETE_ITEM';
```

and here's mern-app/client/src/reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import itemReducer from './itemReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    item: itemReducer
});
```

and finally here's mern-app/client/src/reducers/itemReducer.js

```
import uuid from 'uuid';
import { GET_ITEMS, ADD_ITEM, DELETE_ITEM } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    items: [
        {id: uuid(), name: 'ali'},
        {id: uuid(), name: 'amgad'},
        {id: uuid(), name: 'nour'},
    ]
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_ITEMS:
            return {
                ...state
            }
        case DELETE_ITEM:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: state.items.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload)
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mismatching the connected component imports and exports.

In `ShoppingList.js`, you have:

```js
// Named export
export class ShoppingList extends Component {}

// Default export
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getItems, deleteItem })(ShoppingList);
```

In `App.js`, you have:

```js
// Named import
import { ShoppingList } from './components/ShoppingList';
```

So, you're importing the *unconnected* version of `ShoppingList` and using it.

Change that to be a default import so that you get the connected version of the component, and it should work:

```js
import ShoppingList from './components/ShoppingList';
```

Comment: Yeah, it works !
Thanks very much @markerikson for your help.